# с++ крестики нолики баг

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте я новенький в мире программирования c++. вот решил устроится стажером в фирму. Первое тестовое задание было сделать игру крестики нолики. Человек против компьютера чтоб компьютер всегда выигрывал. Вот взял шаблон с видео-уроков Дениса Маркова. Но что то не то не могу найти баг после 3-4 ходов прога проста не реагирует.
Пожалуйста помогите.

personvscomp.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<random>
#include<conio.h>
int n;
using namespace std;
class personvscomp {
protected:
    char name1[30];
    char name2[30]="computer";
    char table[3][3];
    bool step;
public:
    void instruction()
    {
        cout << "\t\t*** Крестики-Нолики***\n\n";
        cout << "Правила:\n";
        cout << "Играют 2 игрока на поле 3x3\n";
        cout << "Побеждает тот кто составит выйграшную комбинацию\n";
        cout << "Вид поля:\n\n";
        int l = 0;

        for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            {
                cout << "| " << l + 1 << ' ';
                table[i][j] = char(49 + l);
                l++;
            }
            cout << '|';
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << "\nДля хода нажмите цифру ячейки поля\n";
        cout << "Для начала игры нажмите клавишу:";
        _getch();
        system("cls");
    }
    bool input()
    {
        for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            {
                cout << "| " << table[i][j] << ' ';
            }
            cout << '|';
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << endl;
        if (step)
            cout << "Ходит " << name1 << " : ";
        else cout << "Ходит " << name2 << " : ";

        if (step)
        {
            cin >> n;
        }
        else
        {
            while (!step)

            {
                /*Нападение*/
             if     (((table[1][0] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')) || ((table[0][2] == 'O') && (table[0][1] == 'O')) || ((table[2][2] == 'O') && (table[1][1] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[0][0] != 'X') && (table[0][0] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 1;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[0][2] == 'O')) || ((table[1][1] == 'O') && (table[2][1] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[0][1] != 'X') && (table[0][1] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 2;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[0][1] == 'O')) || ((table[1][2] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')) || ((table[1][1] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[0][2] != 'X') && (table[0][2] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 3;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')) || ((table[1][1] == 'O') && (table[1][2] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[1][0] != 'X') && (table[1][0] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 4;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')) || ((table[2][0] == 'O') && (table[0][2] == 'O')) || (((table[1][2] == 'O') && (table[1][0] == 'O')) || ((table[0][1] == 'O') && (table[2][1] == 'O'))))
            {
                if ((table[1][1] != 'X') && (table[1][1] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 5;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[1][0] == 'O') && (table[1][1] == 'O')) || ((table[0][2] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[1][2] != 'X') && (table[1][2] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 6;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[1][0] == 'O')) || ((table[2][1] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')) || ((table[0][2] == 'O') && (table[1][1] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[2][0] != 'X') && (table[2][0] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 7;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][1] == 'O') && (table[1][1] == 'O')) || ((table[2][0] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[2][1] != 'X') && (table[2][1] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 8;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[2][0] == 'O') && (table[2][1] == 'O')) || ((table[0][2] == 'O') && (table[1][2] == 'O')) || ((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[1][1] == 'O')))
            {
                if ((table[2][2] != 'X') && (table[2][2] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 9;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[0][2] == 'O')) && ((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')))
            {
                if (((table[0][1] != 'O') && (table[0][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][0] != 'O') && (table[1][0] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 2,4 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l - 1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[0][2] == 'O')) && ((table[0][2] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')))
            {
                if (((table[0][1] != 'O') && (table[0][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][2] != 'O') && (table[1][2] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 2,6 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l - 1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')) && ((table[2][2] == 'O') && (table[2][0] == 'O')))
            {
                if (((table[2][1] != 'O') && (table[2][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][0] != 'O') && (table[1][0] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 8,4 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l - 1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[2][0] == 'O') && (table[2][2] == 'O')) && ((table[2][0] == 'O') && (table[0][0] == 'O')))
            {
                if (((table[2][1] != 'O') && (table[2][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][2] != 'O') && (table[1][2] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 8,6 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l - 1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /*Нападение*/

            /*Оборона*/
            else if (((table[0][2] == 'X') && (table[0][1] == 'X')) || ((table[2][0] == 'X') && (table[1][0] == 'X')) || ((table[2][2] == 'X') && (table[1][1] == 'X')))
                {
                    if ((table[0][0] != 'X') && (table[0][0] != 'O'))
                    {
                        n = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[0][2] == 'X')) || ((table[1][1] == 'X') && (table[2][1] == 'X')))
                {
                    if ((table[0][1] != 'X') && (table[0][1] != 'O'))
                    {
                        n = 2;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[0][1] == 'X')) || ((table[1][2] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')) || ((table[1][1] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')))
                {
                    if ((table[0][2] != 'X') && (table[0][2] != 'O'))
                    {
                        n = 3;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')) || ((table[1][1] == 'X') && (table[1][2] == 'X')))
                {
                    if ((table[1][0] != 'X') && (table[1][0] != 'O'))
                    {
                        n = 4;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')) || ((table[0][2] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')) || ((table[0][1] == 'X') && (table[2][1] == 'X')) || ((table[1][2] == 'X') && (table[1][0] == 'X')))
            {
                if ((table[1][1] != 'X')&& (table[1][1] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 5;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

            }   
            else if (((table[0][2] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')) || ((table[1][0] == 'X') && (table[1][1] == 'X')))
                {
                if ((table[1][2] != 'X') && (table[1][2] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 6;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[1][0] == 'X')) || ((table[1][1] == 'X') && (table[0][2] == 'X')) || ((table[2][1] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')))
                {
                    if ((table[2][0] != 'X') && (table[2][0] != 'O'))
                    {
                        n = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            else if (((table[2][0] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')) || ((table[1][1] == 'X') && (table[0][1] == 'X')))
                {
                if ((table[2][1] != 'X') && (table[2][1] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 8;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
                }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[1][1] == 'X')) || ((table[0][2] == 'X') && (table[1][2] == 'X')) || ((table[2][0] == 'X') && (table[2][1] == 'X')))
            {
                if ((table[2][2] != 'X') && (table[2][2] != 'O'))
                {
                    n = 9;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[0][2] == 'X')) && ((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')))
            {
                if  (((table[0][1] != 'O') && (table[0][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][0] != 'O') && (table[1][0] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 2,4 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l-1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[0][2] == 'X')) && ((table[0][2] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')))
            {
                if  (((table[0][1] != 'O') && (table[0][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][2] != 'O') && (table[1][2] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 2,6 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l-1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[0][0] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')) && ((table[2][2] == 'X') && (table[2][0] == 'X')))
            {
                if (((table[2][1] != 'O') && (table[2][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][0] != 'O') && (table[1][0] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 8,4 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l-1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else if (((table[2][0] == 'X') && (table[2][2] == 'X')) && ((table[2][0] == 'X') && (table[0][0] == 'X')))
            {
                if (((table[2][1] != 'O') && (table[2][1] != 'X')) && ((table[1][2] != 'O') && (table[1][2] != 'X')))
                {
                    int array1[2] = { 8,6 };
                    int l;
                    l = rand() % 2;
                    n = array1[l-1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                srand(time(NULL));
                int array[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
                int k;
                k = rand() % 9;
                n = array[k-1];
                break;

            }
            }
        }
            if (n < 1 || n > 9)
            return false;
        int i, j;

        if (n % 3 == 0)
        {
            i = n / 3 - 1;
            j = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            j = n % 3 - 1;
            i = n / 3;
        }

        if (table[i][j] == 'O' || table[i][j] == 'X')
            return false;

        if (step)
        {
            table[i][j] = 'X';
            step = false;
        }
        else { table[i][j] = 'O'; step = true; }
        return true;
    }
    bool win()
    {
        for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
            if ((table[i][0] == table[i][1]) && (table[i][0] == table[i][2]))
                return true;

            else
                if ((table[0][i] == table[1][i]) && (table[0][i] == table[2][i]))
                    return true;

                else if ((table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[0][0] == table[2][2]) || (table[0][2] == table[1][1] && table[0][2] == table[2][0]))
                    return true;


        return false;
    }

    int main1() {
        //int i = 0;

        cout << "Введите имя игрока: ";
        cin >> name1;


        /*srand(time(NULL));
        if (rand() & 1)//
            step = true;
        else step = false;
        */

        while (!win())
        {
            //if (i == 9)
            //{
                //cout << "Ничья!!";
                //_getch();
                //return -1;
        //  }
            system("cls");
            if (!input())
            {
                /*cout << "Вы ввели неверные данные повторите!" << endl;
                _getch();*/
                continue;
            }
        //  i++;
        }

        system("cls");
        if (step)
            cout << "Победил " << name2 << endl;
        else cout << "Победил " << name1 << endl;


        _getch();
    }
};
```

source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<random>
#include<time.h>
#include"person vs person.h"
#include"comp vs comp.h"
#include"person vs comp.h"
using namespace std;

void greetings() 
{
    system("Color B2");
    cout << "***Добро пожаловать в игру крестики нолики***" << endl;
    cout << "***Выберите режим игры и нажмите клавишу ENTER***" << endl;
    cout << "1 Против Компьютера\n";
    cout << "2 Против Человека \n";
    cout << "3 Компьютер против компьютера: ";
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    int n;
    greetings();
    cin >> n;
    system("cls");
    while (true)
    {
        if (n < 1 || n>3)
        {
            cout << "Вы ввели неправильный номер пожалуйста повторите: ";
            cin >> n;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    if (n == 1)
    {
        personvscomp *ptr = new personvscomp;
        ptr->instruction();
        ptr->main1();
    }
    /*else if (n == 2)
    {
        personvsperson *dp = new personvsperson;
        system("cls");
        dp->instruction();
        _getch();
        system("cls");
        dp->main1();
        _getch();

    }
    else if (n == 3)
    {
        compvscomp *ptr = new compvscomp;
        ptr->instruction();
        ptr->main1();

    }*/
    else
    {
        cerr << "Произошла ошибка!!!";
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Поправте формат кода.

Comment: интересно найдётся ли кто то кому будет не лень разбираться в этой целой туче условных веток

Comment: Как бы Вас не смущает, что выиграть в крестики-нолики невозможно?

Comment: Скорее всего Вы не учли все состояния игрового поля. Нужно время чтобы разобраться в коде)

Comment: да даже мой учитель не смог разобраться )))lol